# Is it possible at half speed of light to explore in space or walk with suits like astronaut do? ( Passengers Movie )

Tags: classical-mechanics, speed-of-light, velocity, inertial-frames, relative-motion

In the film Passenger the spaceship was flying at half light speed  so I was thinking was it even possible that like chris pratt one can go out of such fast moving ship with just the rope tied not even dragged by it.I know its not possible for half light speed in first place but just a thought.

Comment: You, as you type your post, are moving arbitrarily close to the speed of light relative to an infinity of (locally) inertial reference frames.

Comment: Study why speed is relative and what it means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity

Comment: Yup I was on that only after the first answer , I do know that but just didn't thought that hard enough   @safesphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed is irrelevant. Astronauts do space walks around spaceships and space stations regularly. In the reference frame of the ship, the astronauts have very small velocities.  The speed of the ship itself is only relative to some other reference frame.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, speed itself is irrelevant. Astronauts would not notice their speed in any way; there will be no drag on the rope.

However, there is another way in which speed is very relevant. As the astronauts are moving at $0.5c$ it means that all other matter they encounter will strike them with that same speed, be that a micrometeorite, or even just an atom. A particle with a mass of $1{\mu}g$ would still have an energy of over $10^7J$. If my calculation is correct, this is equivalent to a 1 ton car hitting you at $140m/s$ or about $500 km/h$. Not something you'd ignore.

Of course $1{\mu}g$ particles are very rare in space but even a hydrogen atom at that speed will penetrate the space suit and cause damage to the astronaut's cells. And space is not completely empty: there are about 1000 atoms per $cm^3$. As our astronauts travel $0.5c =150\times10^6m/s$ they will sweep through $150\times10^8cm$, times their surface area, every second. That amounts to quite a few hits!

Comment: *... all other matter they encounter will strike them with that same speed.* This seems to contradict your 1st sentence. Also it assumes that the *other matter* is at rest in the frame of reference wrt which the astronauts are moving at 0.5c. Why should the *other matter* be at rest in that particular frame of reference? Cosmic ray particles come from all directions.

Comment: @sammy I'm talking about galactic matter, which moves at no more than hundreds of km/s relative to the galaxy, so their effective speed is still 0.5c. I'm ignoring things like cosmic rays, which move far faster, but they are also much rarer.

Comment: I think things are much worse than even your last paragraph implies: at $c/2$ the collisions would induce thermonuclear reactions. Let's say that each such reaction lets slip about 1MeV. A $10^4{\rm cm^2}$ area sweeping through $1.5\times 10^{10}{\rm cm\,s^{-1}}$ would trigger of the order of $10^{17}$ of these reactions each second. Our astronaut would be cooked by a steady reaction output of about $10{\rm kW}$. It would be utterly impossible to travel at $c/2$ relative to any matter. In practice this would mostly mean significant fractions of $c$ relative to the Hubble flow.

Comment: [This](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/) is also essential reading here. BTW you beat me to this answer you complete skumbag :), which for me is inspired by Munroe's article

Comment: @Rod Indeed, thanks for that link. I thought it was bad enough without going into more detail. I also ignored correcting the energy for relativistic effects, which would make it worse again.